# powerbi embed: invalid grant: consent_required

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to get the Bearer token from PowerBI REST API in order to embed report.
I follow all the steps I found in videos and around, but something is still wrong, as I get an "invalid grant", suberror: "consent required".
Here all the steps

1. create a workspace in powerBI

[image]

2. create a report
   [image]
3. save report

[image]

4. register app. (home url, does it matter? I wrote a fake one. is this the problem?)

[image]

5. success, take note of ids

[image]

6. azure: register app

[image]

7. API permission (note that Grant admin consent seems already checked active, I don't have a button)

[image]

8. call from postma: invalid grant

[image]

Don't know what to do. Everybody seems to have it working except me...

Comment: It's not that you don't have a button because it's already granted, but it looks like you don't have rights to do that. Ask your tenant admin instead.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov yeah exactly, who is my tenant admin? I've just opened a trial account myself, there is nobody else. Should I upgrade or something? or look for another kind of account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to use "embed for your organization" you don't need the admin grant for the application.

You should turn "Access Tokens" under "Implicit grant" on the app "Authentication" page:

[image: Azure portal Authentication page]

However, I am not sure what you are trying to do, you can't get a Bearer token from the Power BI REST APIs, you can get an embed token that you can provide for your end users if you are using "embed for your customers"

You can see examples for both here: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/